# Python Ctypes Keyboard Event

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard, ctypes, pywin32

I have some Python 2.7 code as follows:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA5, 0, 0, 0) # Right Menu Key
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0, 0) # F4

ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0) #Enter Key
```

Whenever I run the code my computer bugs out, even after I close Python. It seems that the <kbd>alt</kbd> key is always pressed. This stops if I manually press the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

Another thing is that this code is meant to close the shell. It only works with the right menu keycode and not the alt keycode nor the left menu keycode. (I know there are other ways to close the shell, but this closes anything.)

Here is what I want to know:

1. Why does this hold down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key?
2. How do I stop this in my code?
3. Why does this not work with the alt keycode or the left-menu keycode?

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps.

Comment: Automating applications by way of faking input is a bad idea. You should use the automation interfaces ([UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx)) instead. For your actual question: You never inject a key-up event, so the system assumes that the [Alt] key is pressed. That is to be expected.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your help but how do I add a key-up event as you said.

Comment: By passing the `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` flag to [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you again, but how do I do this in Python. I'm new to this. Could you give me an example, please.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, but I believe the issue lies in the fact that you aren't simulating the key up command. Adding the three lines of code below should be able to simulate what you are looking for.

For the below code, I am assuming that you want it sequentially(i.e. press the right menu key, press the F4 key, then press enter). If, however, you want to hold it down, as in the case of Shift + 'a', you would call both key down events then both key up events.

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA5, 0, 0, 0) # Right Menu Key Down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0xA5, 0, 0x0002, 0) # Right Menu Key Up
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0, 0) # F4 Down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x73, 0, 0x0002, 0) # F4 Up
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0) #Enter Key Down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0x0002, 0) #Enter Key Up
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. I figured it out... but for future visitors, it's good!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) to emulate user input. Your problem is already solved inside it. Submodule [pywinauto.keyboard](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html) can be used so:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys
SendKeys('%{F4}{PAUSE 0.2}{ENTER}') # press Alt+F4, pause, press Enter
```

Just run `pip install pywinauto` in a command line before.