# Emulating click in Python for a subprocess that requires a click to finish

Tags: python, subprocess, wait, keypress

I am trying to automate some tasks using Python. The task involves running some .exe code, and the .exe code, at the end needs user to press a key to finish. Here is my problem:

In my code I need to run the .exe two times, so my code looks like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('MyCode.exe')
PressKey(13)
p.wait()
...
p = subprocess.Popen('MyCode.exe')
PressKey(13)
p.wait()
```

And the `PressKey()` function is copied from [HERE](https://gist.github.com/Aniruddha-Tapas/1627257344780e5429b10bc92eb2f52a).

My problem is that it looks like the first `PressKey(13)` function call works and causes the .exe subproces to finish and python will move on to the next line, but then the second time the subprocess is executed the `PressKey(13)` does not have any effect and the .exe code stays at the stage that asks user to press a key. I even tried adding a `PressKey(13)` after the `p.wait()` as well and it didn't help.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: It might have to do with which task is in the foreground.  The key is probably being sent, but to the wrong window.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make sure my task is in the foreground?

Comment: I used to know how, but haven't been on Windows for years.  in Linux it would be `xdotool search --name MyCode windowactivate`.  *Automate the boring stuff with Python* comes to mind.  **SO** might have answers, but you'd have to scrounge around.

Comment: I looked at that book, it suggest to use `pyautogui` module. Unfortunately I cannot install any module and need to use whatever is already provided in python standard library. Any other suggestion? Thanks again.

Comment: a subprocess call to an [AutoHotKey script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autohotkey)?

Comment: You probably could do it with `ctypes`, but you'd have to study those function calls.  Think this shows how to [locate the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501191/how-to-get-windows-window-names-with-ctypes-in-python) Then you might [send a key combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724561/python-ctypes-keyboard-event) to raise it.  If you can't find the keycode there, search GitHub for `Python keyboard ctypes`

Comment: oh wait, `PressKey(13)` is Pause.  I thought that was Enter.  Ya might try `PressKey(0D)` instead.  --  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes.  or Alt-Tab...  figure out what that key-combo is.

Comment: isn't '0D' in hex the same as 13 in decimal? the argument in PressKey()  is decimal.

Comment: oh yea yea, was expecting to see `0x` and it threw me off.